# How to concat time with present date in MS SQL while converting from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Here is **Mysql code:**

```
select concat(date_format(now(),'%Y/%m/%d'),' ','06:00:00 AM')
```

Trying to concat date with time, getting error like: required two parameters to concat.

**MS SQL:**

```
select concat((CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102),' ','06:00:00 AM')); *not working while converting from mysql to sql*
```

Comment: There is problem with brackets. It should be: select concat((CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102)),' ','06:00:00 AM');

Comment: You've tagged both SQL Server 2008 and 2012.  The problem with this is 2012 solutions don't always work in 2008.  [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh231515.aspx) is a great example.  You cannot use it in 2008.  Can I suggest you use one or the other, this will increase the odds that the posted answers work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
Select CONCAT( CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102),' 06:00:00 AM') 

Or 
select CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102) + ' 06:00:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` is not recognized in `SQL Server`. this code should work -

```
select CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102)+' '+'06:00:00 AM';
```

Comment: CONCAT is available since SQL2012.

Comment: Thanks. I am still on 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with brackets. It should be:

```
select concat((CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102)),' ','06:00:00 AM');
```